# Multiple select statements in single query while using 'group by' and 'join'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables -

`podcasts`, `videos` and `others`.

Each of the entities under these are associated with a `category` and `subcategories`.

Example for podcasts -

[image]

This category_id and subcategory_id have their name values in their respective tables -

[image] [image]

Now, I want to get the count of podcasts, videos and text under each category & subcategory combination. My individual SQL query are these -

For `podcasts` -

```
SELECT c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(p.*) AS podcast_count
FROM podcasts p
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = p.podcast_category_id
JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.sub_category_id = p.podcast_subcategory_id
WHERE p.podcast_owner = 14 AND p.podcast_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

For `others` -

```
SELECT c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(o.*) AS other_count
FROM otherlinks o
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = o.other_link_category_id
JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.sub_category_id = o.other_link_subcategory_id
WHERE o.other_link_owner = 14 AND o.other_link_add_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

And similar one for `videos`

Now, I want to combine them into a single query so that I get three columns for counts in a single result - `podcast_count`, `other_count` and `videos_count`. How do I do that?

Comment: Just add the two missing `xx_count` columns to each of the three queries (`, 0 AS other_count, 0 AS videos_count ` for the first one) then `UNION` them.

Comment: Could you please give an example in the answer section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the `CROSS` join of `categories` to `sub_categories`, so you get all the combinations of categories and subcategories,  to the other 3 tables with `LEFT` joins and group by each combination and aggregate:

```
select c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name,
       count(distinct p.podcast_id) podcast_count,
       count(distinct v.video_id) videos_count,  
       count(distinct o.other_link_id) other_count 
from categories c cross join sub_categories sc
left join podcasts p on (p.podcast_category_id, p.podcast_subcategory_id) = (c.category_id, sc.sub_category_id)
  and p.podcast_owner = 14 AND p.podcast_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
left join videos v on (v.video_category_id, v.video_subcategory_id) = (c.category_id, sc.sub_category_id)
  and v.video_owner = 14 AND v.video_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
left join otherlinks o on (o.other_link_category_id, o.other_link_subcategory_id) = (c.category_id, sc.sub_category_id)
  and o.other_link_owner = 14 AND o.other_link_add_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
where coalesce(p.podcast_id, v.video_id, o.other_link_id) is not null
group by c.category_id, c.category_name, sc.sub_category_id, sc.sub_category_name
```

The WHERE clause filters out any combination of category and subcategory that does not contain any podcast, video or other link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNION ALL` and add a constant to distinguish them.

```
SELECT 'podcasts' as "rowtype", c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(p.*) AS type_count
FROM podcasts p
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = p.podcast_category_id
JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.sub_category_id = p.podcast_subcategory_id
WHERE p.podcast_owner = 14 AND p.podcast_upload_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3

UNION ALL
SELECT 'videos' as "rowtype", c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(o.*) AS type_count
FROM videolinks o
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = o.other_link_category_id
JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.sub_category_id = o.other_link_subcategory_id
WHERE o.other_link_owner = 14 AND o.other_link_add_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3

UNION ALL
SELECT 'other' as "rowtype", c.category_name, sc.sub_category_name, count(o.*) AS type_count
FROM otherlinks o
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = o.other_link_category_id
JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.sub_category_id = o.other_link_subcategory_id
WHERE o.other_link_owner = 14 AND o.other_link_add_time_stamp >= timestamp '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

I want to note that even just `union` might work, but `union all` is more often than not the one that gives the desired result.